# 4 way flip flop relay?

Tags: relay

I have a small project which involves controlling 4 solenoids with one hall effect switch. I want to use the switch to cycle through the solenoids. Each time the hall effect switch is triggered i want to switch on the next solenoid...

A flip flop relay seems to do what I want for a single load... but I can't figure out a solution to drive 4 solenoids...

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Round-robin or do you want to leave the prior solenoid engaged while the next one is turned on. I can't tell from the writing. If round-robin, do you want to turn off the prior one BEFORE turning on the next one? Or is a short overlap period where two are on okay? Try writing more.

Comment: I should have been more clear... the solenoids are in 2 pairs let's call them 1a, 1b, 2a, 2b... i want them to cycle like this. 

1a on, 2b on, others off
1a on, 2a on, others off
2a on, 1b on, others off
1b on, 2b on, others off
2b on, 1a on, others off
Repeat...

No overlap necessary... if that's not clear enough I'll draw a diagram to illustrate...

Comment: Yeah. A diagram. You write out five states, but I can't tell the difference between the first and last one: 1a on 2b on ... 2b on 1a on. Looks like the same two are on either way. Are there four or five distinct states?

Comment: 4 distinct states, 1 and 5 are the same... intended to illustrate the loop... I'll draw something out.

Comment: What voltage do these solenoids run off of?  Also, what logic supply do you have available to you?

Answer (score 1):

I think I get it. Assuming you want to do this with flip flops, it would look like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVbCnC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If your Hall Effect sensor provides one full clock pulse, then the twisted Johnson counter will advance one step. It goes through four states: 00, 10, 11, 01. These are then translated into the pairs you expressed.

I would have used the \$\overline{Q}\$ outputs had the schematic editor allowed it for their D-flops, so something like this does the same thing without those NOT gates:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faX9x3.png)</sup>

It produces the following:

$$\begin{array}{cccc}
1A&1B&2A&2B \\
1&0&0&1 \\
1&0&1&0 \\
0&1&1&0 \\
0&1&0&1
\end{array}$$

And then returns to the top.

Do something to ensure that both flip flops are reset correctly at power up, too. You'll also have to figure out how to drive your solenoids from these values. That's another subject, though. And since I have NO IDEA at all what your circumstances are, I can't even begin to help on that score.

---

Try out the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faqzw6.png)</sup>

I've included one example LED output driver, too. You'll need four of those if you plan to look at four LED-visible outputs at the same time. I assumed a standard red LED operating at \$20\:\textrm{mA}\$ and requiring only \$2\:\textrm{V}\$ to operate. I think the CD4013 will power up okay with both FF cleared. But that's for testing. Technically, you probably should include a small RC circuit (at least) to create a reset pulse for your final device.

Comment: Logically that looks like the right solution

Comment: Logically that looks like the right solution, but I'm not sure how to implement it practically... nows probably a good time to mention that I'm not an electrical engineer... my system will be working off 12v and the solenoids are rated to 2A. Thanks for your help...

Comment: @user1473810 Is the 12 V the ONLY supply rail available? Is it also used to operate the solenoids?

Comment: Yes and yes... only 1 x 12V power source

Comment: @user1473810 Sounds like you will want to use the CMOS 4013 dual D flip flop package, then. They are cheap and readily available and they work off of 12 V, too. So that's nice. The rest is mostly about driving the solenoids.

Comment: @user1473810 I still know absolutely NOTHING about your Hall sensor details. There's still no way to design without that. Probably should also have the exact specs for the solenoids (datasheet, part number, whatever.)

Comment: @user1473810 Finally, given the CD4013 (or similar), different manufacturers guarantee different amounts of sink/source current. To be safe and well under the worst case limits of the worst manufacturer I could find, shouldn't expect more than \$500\:\mu\textrm{A}\$ of sink/source drive. Yet you want to drive 2 A. That's a current gain of 4000! So it will take a little circuitry.

Comment: OK... Thanks for pointing me at the CD4013... I think I can work with that...

The hall effect switch is this a HKZ-101 (https://www.jaycar.com.au/hkz-101-hall-effect-device-re-introduced/p/ZD1900) and the solenoids are these ones: (http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/400935350019?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT),

Once I've figured out the switching logic, I was just going to use some DPDT relays (RT424F12) to control the solenoids...

Comment: @user1473810 Looks like the hall effect device is perfect. Very easy to use, too. No problems there. I'm not sure why you want to use latching relays (the D FF output will hold the relay with suitable driver circuit.) Do you know what operating current is required for the coils are in your 2-coil bistable relays? Are you okay with keeping a current engaged? Or do you want them pulsed for 20 ms or so?

Comment: I just bought a CD4013 from Jaycar and tried to mock up the schematic you presented earlier, but it's not working at all. I'm just using small lights (not LEDs) as the loads for now (1a, 1b, 2a, 2b). I also had a light on the hall effect sensor as an indicator. The Hall effect sensor is normally high (1), when you introduce iron to the gap it goes low (0). In the circuit I built, ALL lights attached to the CD4013 act together, and opposite to the Hall effect light. i.e. Hall effect goes low, then 1a, 1b, 2a, 2b all go high, and vice versa... Any ideas?

Comment: @user1473810 Do what you can to present the exact circuit you are using. Include the LEDs and any current limiting resistors, too. Everything. I know you are using 12 V, so just point out where that and ground are connected. Pin numbers, too. The outputs of the D flops \$Q\$ and \$\overline{Q}\$ cannot have the same value. That's a given. So all I know is that either the CD4013 is dead or you are asking it to do things it can't do.

Comment: OK, so this is the circuit I created to test your original suggestion: https://s18.postimg.org/o8sn5pkh5/Circuit_1.png (forgive the highschool quality sketch).
I also tried a more simplified circuit (similar to one I found online): https://s11.postimg.org/rxf0vxvir/Circuit_2.png. This simple circuit didn't work either.
I noticed during this test that the 4013 chip was really hot, so I looked into the power ratings (I probably should have started here). My power supply is rated at 12V 0.7A, but the 4013 is rated to 10mA on any input... Suspect I've cooked it now...

Comment: @user1473810 It is probably gone. Next time, just hook up +12 V and ground to it. Nothing else. Then check the supply current. Should be well below 1 mA. If not, something is seriously wrong and you need to solve that, first. Next, you need to convince me that you are working your Hall sensor correctly. Are you using a pull up resistor for its output? Or not? (You should be.) And, UNDER NO CIRCUMSTANCES should you draw any more than 1 mA from Q or /Q outputs.

Comment: @user1473810 If you want to drive an LED with those outputs, then USE A TRANSISTOR and a couple of resistors in the usual fashion. The Q and /Q outputs will go to the base via one of those resistors.

Comment: @user1473810 I've added a schematic to my answer. Hopefully, that helps some.

Comment: Also, don't forget the power-on-reset!  A TL7712 should do the job for that...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I think I mentioned something about that. See the final sentence I wrote. (And it seems, the last paragraph of my first edit before adding more, later.)

Comment: @jonk -- yeah, you mentioned that one would be needed -- I was seconding your suggestion :)